# assembly 8086, count even numbers in array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

So I came across one example in my box for assembly 8086 and i could use some help with completing the code

So example goes like this: there is an array of integers, calculate number of even elements in the array

```
.model small
.stack
.data
arr dw 10 dup (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
msg db 'number of even elements is:', '$'   ;;
.code
;printing
print proc a:word

        push bp
        mov bp, sp

        mov ax, a
        mov cx, 10
        mov bx, 0
        cmp ax, 0  

        jne begin
        mov dl, 0
        add dl, '0'
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h
        jmp toend

    begin: 
        cmp ax, 0
        je print

        mov dx, 0
        div cx

        push dx
        inc bx
        jmp begin

    print:   

        cmp bx, 0
        je kraj

        pop dx
        add dl, '0'
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h

        dec bx
        jmp print

toend:
        mov dl, 10 
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h

        pop bp
        ret 2

print endp

main:

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, ;number
    call print
    jmp fin
```

I looked at some previous code and somehow tried to make this work..

So my question is am I at right path at all, should I use `idiv` instruction or?

EDIT:
I can't seem to get anything else beside "21243" as a result, and by the way i tried to calculate some other things and got lost in the process,here's the complete code:

```
; there is an array of integers.  calculate the number of
; even elements in the array.

.model small
.stack
.data
arr dw 10 dup (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
msg db 'Average (in procents): ', '$'
msg1 db 'Average of even elements: ', '$'
msg2 db 'Sum  is:', '$'  ;;
msg3 db 'Number of even elements is :', '$'   ;;
limit dw ? ; length * 2, because we save dw (length of 2 bytes)
number dw 2345     ;;
sum dw 0   ;;
.code
print proc a:word

        push bp
        mov bp, sp

        mov ax, a
        mov cx, 10
        mov bx, 0
        cmp ax, 0  

        jne begining
        mov dl, 0
        add dl, '0'
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h
        jmp toend

    begining:
        cmp ax, 0
        je print

        mov dx, 0
        div cx

        push dx
        inc bx
        jmp begining

    print:  

        cmp bx, 0
        je toend

        pop dx
        add dl, '0'
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h

        dec bx
        jmp print

toend:
        mov dl, 10
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h

        pop bp
        ret 2

print endp

main:

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, number
    call print
    jmp fin




    shl ax, 1           ;mul 2
    mov limit, ax

    mov bx, 0
    mov cx, 2

poc:

    cmp bx, limit
    je k

    mov ax, arr[bx]
    ;mov dx, 0 ;
    ;div cx    ;
    cwd

    idiv cx  ;signed division
    cmp dx, 0
    jne  jumpp

    mov ax, number
    inc ax
    mov number, ax

    mov ax, sum
    add ax, arr[bx]
    mov sum, ax

jumpp:

    add bx, 2 ;because 'length' of elements is 2 bytes
    jmp poc

k:

    mov ax, 100
    mov bx, number
    mul bx

    mov dx, 0     ; xor dx, dx
    mov bx, length arr  ; length of array = 10 so this is mov bx, 10
    div bx    

    mov es, ax
    mov dl, offset msg
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ax, es
    push ax
    call print

    ; mov dl, offset msg2
    ; mov ah, 9
    ; int 21h

    mov ax, sum
    push ax
    call print

    ; mov dl, offset msg3
    ; mov ah, 9
    ; int 21h

    mov ax, number
    push ax
    call print

    ; mov dl, offset msg1
    ; mov ah, 9
    ; int 21h

    mov ax, sum
    mov dx, 0
    cwd
    mov bx, number
    cmp bx, 0
    je here
    idiv number

    push ax
    call print
    jmp fin

here:
    mov dl, 0
    add dl, '0'
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

fin:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

end main
```

Comment: `div cx` with `cx=10` would divide by 10 not 2 obviously. Also you never even use the result. While using division is fine in the general case, for powers of two you normally use bitwise operatins.

Comment: will this work for division by 2?
`mov cx, 2  ;;

idiv cx  ;; 

push ax`

Comment: Yes that will work, although it's unclear why you are pushing the result to the stack, especially since your question title says "count".

Comment: For that i'm trying also in the same code to calculate length,sum,average

Comment: None of which require the saving of the quotient on the stack.

Comment: `idiv` or `div` will work only with valid input values, your piece of code doesn't seem to set them up correctly, consult the x86 instruction manual for details about `div` or `idiv`. ... (oh, actually there's `mov dx,0`... I'm blind already. But that will work only for non-negative values, while `idiv` is rather used for signed math)

Comment: i'll try to finish this, probably gonna need some more help

Comment: edited and got stuck again..

Comment: The best way to count even numbers is probably to count odd numbers and do `even = length - odd`.  Odd numbers have their low bit set, so you can do `odd += (*p++) & 1`.  e.g. `lodsw` / `and ax, 1` / `add dx, ax`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov ax, number
> call print
> jmp fin
> ```

Don't think about counting even numbers for now. First you need to get displaying the number right.
Also because of the `jmp fin` instruction none of the additional instructions is executed anyway.

Your *print* procedure has several problems:

- You end it with `ret 2` which means that it should be called with a word-sized argument pushed on the stack, but there isn't!
- You've passed the argument via the `AX` register, but almost immediately you destroy it with `mov ax, a`.
- Your *print* procedure contains a label with the same name *print*. Knowing that emu8086 is kind of broken software, I coudn't tell that the `call print` instruction reaches the procedure or the label.

Next code should work. Verify that it does and build upon it. Add small things to it (just a few lines of code) and don't continue adding more until it works as it should!

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    number dw 2345

.code

; IN (ax) OUT () MOD (ax,bx,cx,dx)
print:
    mov  cx, 10     ; Constant divider
    mov  bx, 0      ; Count pushes
  divide:
    mov  dx, 0      ; Dividing DX:AX
    div  cx
    push dx
    inc  bx
    cmp  ax, 0
    jne  divide
  show:
    pop  dx         ; Always at least 1 pop here
    add  dl, '0'
    mov  ah, 02h    ; DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int  21h
    dec  bx
    jnz  show
    mov  dl, 10     ; Linefeed, Don't you need carry return (13) too?
    mov  ah, 02h
    int  21h
    ret

main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, number
    call print
    jmp fin

    ...

fin:
    mov  ax, 4C00h  ; DOS.Terminate
    int  21h

end main
```

For further reading and to better understand why the above code works see 
[Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos)